# Perforce: how can I rename a directory name

Tags: version-control, perforce

My p4 stream is `//ui/main` and I have many files under `//ui/main/src/`. How can I rename `src` to be something else like `apps`?

I tried

```
p4 edit src/
```

I got this error:

```
src - files(s) not on client
```

The following doesn't work either:

```
p4 move src/... apps/...
```

I am using Linux so I am seeking a commandline solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p4 edit src/...
p4 move src/... apps/...
```

Note that your stream needs to have `apps/...` in it!  E.g. this will work fine for any path you want to put in this stream:

```
Stream: //ui/main
Paths:
    share ...
```

but if your stream looks like this:

```
Stream: //ui/main
Paths:
    share src/...
```

then the `apps/...` path doesn't exist in your stream and you won't be able to move things into it.  (To fix this, add `apps/...` to your `Paths` *before* you do the `move`.)